# Javascript: regex to replace only isolated string

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if this question has already been answered, but I want to replace 'um mil' with 'mil' but not when 'un mil' is preceded or followed by another string.

---

Text: um mil

Desired Outcome: mil

---

Text: veinte um mil

Desired Outcome (should remain unchanged): veinte um mil

---

So far I've tried the following:

```
(\bum mil\b,'')
```

and

```
('^um mil$','')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close:

```
"um mil".replace(/^um mil/, "mil"); // "mil"
"veinte um mil".replace(/^um mil/, "mil"); // "veinte um mil"
```

Keep in mind that `/^um mil/` is not the same as `'^um mil'`. One is a regular expression, the other is a string. It can be a little bit confusing because sometimes you pass a regular expression as a string.

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^un mil");
// is equivalent to
var regexp = /^un mil/;
```

Comment: Thanks Halcyon! That fixed my issue. I'm new to coding so I really appreciate the help.